gsutil mv command is copying but not deleting the folder
I am trying to move one folder and its files from gcs location to another by gsutil command, it is coping the folder and file to target but not deleting the folder from source, the folder is dynamic
gsutil mv gs://bucket_name/source/landing/* gs://bucket/target/
gsutil mv gs://bucket_name/source/landing/* gs://bucket/target/
output: The folder inside landing copies to target/ location but the same folder without data remains in source also it should be deleted as per move command functionality.
